# Python, output two lists differences with * wildcard

Tags: python, list, set, compare

I'm having a hard time with python and finding differences between two lists.

**CMDB** list:

```
ABC:NL1:SB6
ABC:NL2:SB6
ABC:NL3:SB6
ABC:NL4:SB6
NL9:SB9
NL5:SB4
NL6:SB7
```

**DB** list:

```
NL1:SB6
NL2:SB6
ABC:NL3:SB6
ABC:NL4:SB6
ABC:NL8:SB8
ABC:NL5:SB4
ABC:NL6:SB7
```

I would like to get output that finds differences:

```
NL9:SB9
ABC:NL8:SB8
```

I have tried

```
cmdb_fin = set(cmdb)
db_fin = set(db)
equal = db_fin.symmetric_difference(cmdb_fin)
```

but the output is like following because it compares exact strings to each other, not like "patterns"

```
ABC:NL5:SB4
NL6:SB7
ABC:NL2:SB6
NL2:SB6
ABC:NL8:SB8
NL5:SB4
ABC:NL6:SB7
NL9:SB9
ABC:NL1:SB6
NL1:SB6
```

Is there any way to get expected by me output?

criteria:
if any given string (block of chars) in CMDB list exists in DB list (it can be only part of a string), it should not be in output as it kinda exists in both lists. And of course in other way -> DB compared to CMD
for example `NL5:SB4` from CMDB list matches `ABC:NL5:SB4` from DB

Comment: Your comparison criteria for finding differences in the lists is not clear. Could you please give more details about it? E.g. why is `ABC:NL5:SB4` not in the desired output?

Comment: because un CMDB list there is ``NL5:SB4``

Comment: Kindly give a view of what is your expected output?

Comment: there is specified in description :)
``NL9:SB9`` and ``ABC:NL8:SB8``

Comment: you mean that when a line contains at least a block of chars of other line, lines are equals ? I think you must explain the equality criteria more clear to help you.

Comment: yes, if any given string (block of chars) in CMDB list exists in DB list (it can be only part of a string), it should not be in output as it kinda exists in both lists. And of course in other way -> DB compared to CMD

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a custom equality comparator when using python sets, you need to define a custom class with `__eq__`, `__ne__`, & `__hash__` defined. Below is an example of how this could be achieved in your case, using the last two elements in each line to define whether two elements are equivalent.

**Code:**

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
        self.key = ':'.join(s.split(':')[-2:])
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.s
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Line):
            return ((self.key == other.key))
        else:
            return False
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return (not self.__eq__(other))
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key)

cmdb = ['ABC:NL1:SB6', 'ABC:NL2:SB6', 'ABC:NL3:SB6', 'ABC:NL4:SB6', 'NL9:SB9',
        'NL5:SB4', 'NL6:SB7']
db = ['NL1:SB6', 'NL2:SB6', 'ABC:NL3:SB6', 'ABC:NL4:SB6', 'ABC:NL8:SB8',
      'ABC:NL5:SB4', 'ABC:NL6:SB7']

cmdb_fin = set(Line(l) for l in cmdb)
db_fin = set(Line(l) for l in db)
equal = db_fin.symmetric_difference(cmdb_fin)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> equal
{ABC:NL8:SB8, NL9:SB9}
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> Line('NL5:SB4') == Line('ABC:NL5:SB4')
True
```